# Create Drag and Drop Elements into TextArea that are predefined conditions

Tags: html, angularjs

What I'm looking for is a way to add custom elements to a text area that an end users can place into a message. These elements would be next to text area and can be clicked and dragged into place where needed.

Example of a message (Elements are in {{ }} ):

```
Hello {{First.Name}},

Your leave request ( {{Leave.Time}} ) has been received.

Thank you,
{{Company.Name}}
```

I've looked for a couple days off and on of an example of this. I did find one that was jQuery but was looking for an AngularJs approach. If anyone has any ideas or a resource I can look at, I would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Adam